# mouseenter and mouseleave events fires multiple times

Tags: mouseevent

what i am trying to do is that, when mouse enters on anchor tag, it displays a div on targated anchor tag and when it leaves i simply hide the div but the problem is that, the mouse enter and mouse leave fires multiple times as i mouse the pointer. i noticed that as i move the pointer ,it leaves the mouse and as i move it again it enters.

the below is the jsbin where the example is. please help. thanks.

http://jsbin.com/jucaqereca/1/edit

Comment: I know it's a workaround at this point, but why not check if the object does not have the class, and if not, add it then?

Comment: i did not get what you said.. can you please be more elaborative??? thanks.

Comment: something like [this](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) - where you check if( $("yourSelector").hasClass("myClass")) You may also find [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) helpful.